# Providing @Table name runtime in JPA

Tags: hibernate, jpa, entity

I have tables for each client, for example, we have a generic table name ABC_ACCOUNTS and we also have it's variants for each client.
For client PQR we have a table PQR_ACCOUNTS
For client XYZ we have a table XYZ_ACCOUNTS

I am using Spring Boot and JPA with Hibernate 5 for creating DB repositories and access the data. I want to be able to access and modify the data based on the request parameter 'client_prefix'.

I tired using `PhysicalNamingStrategy` but it seems it only changes the table names on server startup and doesn't get call later. This means I get to change the Entity tables only ones and that too at the startup time.

Is there any way I can do it by changing at the request level?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's possible. You can use the multi-tenancy feature of Hibernate to switch schemas, but switching tables is not possible. You would have to create an entity per table. You could use a base entity containing the structure and use the table per class inheritance strategy. That way, the mappings for customer tables are simple: `@Entity @Table(name = "XYZ_ACCOUNTS") public class XyzAccounts extends AbstractAccounts {}`